# Change page in pdfbox with Button

Tags: image, pdf, javafx, pdfbox

I'm working in JavaFX with PDFbox and I have this problem. I want to scroll Scroll through the  pages of a pdf by clicking a button(when I press it I want to go to the next page). When I open the pdf then I show the first page with this code:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage (500,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null);
                BufferedImage firstpage = new BufferedImage (500,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                firstpage = pdPages.get(0).convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 100);
                Image primapagina = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(firstpage, null);
                ImageView v ;
                v = new ImageView(primapagina);
```

Then I created a button like this:

```
Button avanti = new Button(">>");
avanti.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial;");
```

Finally I created the handler,

```
avanti.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
//                  final int j = i;

                        BufferedImage Xpage = null;

                        try { 

                            Xpage = pdPages.get(8).convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 100);
//                          System.out.printf("\n firstpage %d",t );
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Image Xpagina = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(Xpage, null);
                    v.setImage(Xpagina);



                    }
                });
```

At the moment I put 8 just to see if it was working, and it was. But How can I ,by clicking the button, go to the next page? I thought about pointers, but I don't think it exist in JavaFX.

Thanks

Comment: Just create a variable:  `private int currentPage ; ` and increment it.

Comment: Thanks @James_D. It was easier than I thought. I also discover that local variables and parameters cannot have public or private modifier.

Comment: What would that modifier mean for a local variable?

Comment: @James_D Because I put your code inside the try-catch block, and then I got the error. That's why I discover this.

Comment: My point was that it doesn't make any sense to put `private` in front of a local variable. What do you think that would mean? I included `private` specifically to indicate that it *wasn't* a local variable.

Comment: I got it @James_D. At the beginning I didn't think about it. That's why I told you. I just thought to put your code inside the try catch block and then run the code. Then I understood there wasn't any sense.